# How to calculate weights proportional to a specific value in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table that looks like the following:

```
id | day | value
-----------------
1  | SUN |  10
1  | MON |  15
1  | TUE |  11
      .
      . 
      .
1  | SAT |  13
2  | SUN |  08
      .
      .
      .
2  | SAT | 22
```

I would like to calculate a new variable called `time_weight` which is the weight of `value` proportional to a specific day. The formula for this would in a programming language like R or Python would look something like `((value - value[day=='TUE']) / value[day=='TUE']) + 1)` so that `time_weight` would equal 1 when `day = 'TUE'` and 1.36 for `id = 1 & day = 'MON'`. I'm curious to know how to do this in Oracle.

EDIT:

Here is my expected output:

```
id | day | value | time_weight
-------------------------------
1  | SUN |  10   |    0.9090
1  | MON |  15   |    1.3636
1  | TUE |  11   |      1
      .
      . 
      .
1  | SAT |  13   |    1.1818 
2  | SUN |  08   |    0.4000
2  | MON |  10   |    0.5000
2  | TUE |  20   |    1.0000
      .
      .
      .
2  | SAT | 22    |    1.1000
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @brittenb . . . presumably you want this for each `id`.

Comment: Updated the question to show desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using window functions:

```
select id, day, value,
       value / max(case when day = 'TUE' then value end) over (partition by id) as time_weight
from t;
```